# "Google Map" property editor in Umbraco... How to set the ApiKey?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, umbraco, umbraco6

I have in an Umbraco (v6) BO a property showing a GoogleMap. The property is like this (the property editor is a "Google Map", as can be seen in the BackOffice's Developer tab).

[image]

so the property displays the map in the Umbraco's BO, but "for development purposes only".

[image]

and, in the console, I see a warning saying:

> Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Supposing I have a Google API key, where should I put it, to remove this message?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? Step 2: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: yes, you sent me the same link I put in the OP, but is not clear *where* should I add this request, in what page, what file?

Comment: Well, if there's no field that you can throw the script in, then maybe code it in the view? (I'm assuming it's MVC).

Comment: what view, this is a BackOffice component

Comment: What I'm saying is that to verify the api you need to basically throw a script in the view (as in the .cshtml). If the developer that created that backoffice didn't do it, you'll have to do it or actually go in the code and throw the verification script.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, found the solution:

The component used in the google maps field is [Google Maps DataType](https://our.umbraco.com/packages/backoffice-extensions/google-maps-datatype/). 
Its sources are [on GitHub](https://github.com/leekelleher/umbraco-google-maps).

We used the 2.0.0 version, that didn't have the API Key field in the BO (as can be seen from the OP screenshot).
Now has to get the sources and recompile the 2.2.0 version, then update the DLL on the server. After that the API Key text field appeared in the BO's (Developer section => DataTypes).

The API Key is the same as for the BO's hosting domain.